# Is there a good adjective for jigsaw pieces that don't match?

Tags: word-request

Is there a good adjective for jigsaw pieces that don't match? I feel like "unfitting" and "non-matching" are not idiomatic and perhaps even incorrect. I was wondering if there were better adjectives that I didn't consider.

Comment: How can jigsaw puzzle pieces be misshapen? Maybe they are just in the wrong place.

Comment: wrong place was what I meant.

Comment: Then, "out of place" might do it. The entire box of pieces fits that description before assembly of the puzzle starts, so I don't think you need a special adjective. Or you could just say "It doesn't go there!". The piece goes somewhere, after all.

Answer (score 2):

> **mismatched** 
>  : unsuitably or wrongly matched. 
>  E.g., *a mismatched pair of socks*

In my opinion, this adjective applies if you have already attempted to put the pieces together. You could also in general say

> They **don’t fit**. / They **don’t fit together**.

Answer (score 0):

We can use simple words.

> Those two pieces are *wrong*.

But your language used in the question is also good.  This is a good situation to use negative expressions:

> Those pieces don't match.  They don't go together. They don't fit